# Select 2 parameters as one concatenated with chars between in postgres

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I would like to get row from Postgres database.
This row in db have to parameters(column): `firstname` and `lastname`.

Regular Select query would download theme as separate fields.
but I would like to concatenate them with dot between them.

I would like to get from row:

`firstname lastname`

one value as follow:
`firstname.lastname`

Currently I do something like this:

`SELECT (firstname, lastname) AS user FROM users`

But In result I am getting:

`(firstname,lastname)`

Can You help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
SELECT (firstname::text || '.'::text || lastname::text) AS user FROM users
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can You tell me how to make result lowercase?

Comment: lower(firstname::text || '.'::text || lastname::text)